# How do I initialize template type variables?

Tags: c++, static-cast, class-template, variable-initialization

```
template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::MyMethod()
{
    // ...

    // Which of the following initialization is better?
    T MyVariable1 = 1;                  // 1st
    T MyVariable2 = 2.0;                // 2nd
    T MyVariable3 = static_cast<T>(3);  // 3rd

    // ...
}
```

Which one is better?

EDIT: `T` is a primitive type.

Comment: What do you mean by "Which one is better?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` can only be a primitive type (`int`, `float`, etc.), I don't think there's any difference; in all cases, the compiler will perform the relevant conversion (and will probably perform the substitution at compile-time).

If `T` is a user-defined type, then obviously these won't compile, unless it has the appropriate constructors defined.  At which point, it may make a difference (e.g. if you have both `T::T(int)` and `T::T(double)` defined).